# C++ library/framework,API for Mixture models in machine learning

Tags: c++, machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition

I want to use Gaussian mixture models  for data clustering ( using an expectation maximization (EM) algorithm, which assigns posterior probabilities to each component density with respect to each observation )  . Is there a c++ library which has Gaussian mixture models implemented alongwith sample dataset and examples?

Answer (score 2):

The [Armadillo C++ library](http://arma.sourceforge.net) has a multi-threaded (parallelised) implementation of k-means and Expectation Maximization (EM) for Gaussian Mixure Models (GMM).

See the [gmm_diag](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#gmm_diag) class for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one [C++ implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmm-gmr/).  However I recommend coding from scratch if you are trying to learn.  This is pretty easy with a decent matrix library.  I have had good success with the [Scythe Statistical Library](http://scythe.wustl.edu/).

It's easy to find sample datasets.  The old [faithful geyser dataset](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/faithful.html) is a classic.

Answer (score 1):

It might be late, But you can take a look at http://itpp.sourceforge.net/current/mog.html

Comment: looks good, are there precompiled bin for MS VC++ 2008/2010 ?

Comment: I am not aware of precompiled for Windows, here is the link to the compilation and installation guide for Windows: http://itpp.sourceforge.net/current/installation.html#msvc

Answer (score 1):

Best that I used is MLPack,
http://www.mlpack.org/doxygen.php?doc=classmlpack_1_1gmm_1_1GMM.html.

You can find a example implementation in my project 
 https://github.com/kerdemdemir/speakerFinder/blob/master/trainer.h

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python sample: http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_classifier.html

Check the underlying implementation.